# Get Cursor Position in Android in Edit Text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am using a custom EditText View. I have overridden the OnKeyUp event and am able to capture the Enter Key press. Now my requirement is, when the user has entered a text "Hi. How are you?" and then keeps the cursor after the word "are" and press enter, I need to get the cursor location so that i can extract the text after the cursor at the moment the Enter Key was pressed. Please let me know how to do this. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can get the Cursor position using the getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd() methods.  If no text is highlighted, both getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd() return the position of the cursor.  So something like this should do the trick:

```
myEditText.getSelectionStart();
```

or

```
myEditText.getSelectionEnd();
```

Then if you want to select all the text after the cursor you could use this:

```
int cursorPosition = myEditText.getSelectionStart();
CharSequence enteredText = myEditText.getText().toString();
CharSequence cursorToEnd = enteredText.subSequence(cursorPosition, enteredText.length());
```

Comment: It may be helpful for some people to know, getSelectionEnd and getSelection start are static methods in the Selection class, not on EditText itself. Here are the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection