# How to get EditText cursor position on Android?

Tags: android, cursor, popupwindow

How to get the edittext cursor position on Android , and show a popup window in this position, in twitter, when you taped '@', it will show a popupwindow, and I want to know how to finish this work.

Comment: You can watch for '@' key event and showing a popup when it's detected.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6900610/706833