# Erasing Character from EditText on Button click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I created an Application to dial particular contact number.
It has one EditText and ten buttons for the digits from 0 to 9 and a BACK button.
I want to erase single digit from EditText on each click event of BACK button.
Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: yes, there is :) but I would prefer to show you what to add to your own code, so please show us what you've got so far

Comment: I have done same as following solution, and All is going fine. But, What if I want to erase from particular position ie. from the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namaskar modiji, try

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
     String text = et.getText().toString();
     if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)){
                String newText = text.substring(1, text.length()); //delete from left
                //or
                String newText1 = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1); //delete from right
                et.setText(newText);
                et.setSelection(newText.length());
                //or
                et.setText(newText1);
                et.setSelection(newText1.length());

     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: What about the position of the Cursor ?

Comment: you can get cursor position by myEditText.getSelectionStart(); or myEditText.getSelectionEnd(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900408/get-cursor-position-in-android-in-edit-text   now use logic as above

Comment: This code causes the first character removal but when click again, it brings back the first click's removal. Interesting.