# Edit text java android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have in my project buttons of numbers button to dial and one button to delete the char next to the cursor(the insert, the line that blinked when writing text).

if I put the cursor in the middle of the string in the edit text, I need to get the position of the cursor in the text.
someone know a method that gives me this information?

I try to use

```
  int pos = _NumberToCall.getSelectionStart();
  String text = _NumberToCall.getText().toString();

  if (pos == _NumberToCall.getText().toString().length()){
                    _NumberToCall.setText(text.substring(0,text.length()-1));
                }else{

   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Cursor Position in Android in Edit Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900408/get-cursor-position-in-android-in-edit-text)

Comment: i need something else

Answer (score 0):

```
  int pos = _NumberToCall.getSelectionStart();
  String text = _NumberToCall.getText().toString();

  if (pos == _NumberToCall.getText().toString().length()){
       _NumberToCall.setText(text.substring(0,text.length()-1));
  }else{
       _NumberToCall.setText( new StringBuilder(text).deleteCharAt(pos).toString());
  }
```