# EditText with no keyboard appear

Tags: android

When I click on the `EditText`, I want:

1. the keyboard will not appear.
2. cursor appear where I press.
3. How can I have the location of the cursor in the code?

Things I tried but not worked:

1. `android:textIsSelectable="true"` - don't show the keyboard neither the cursor.
2. `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` - don't show the keyboard until I press on the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

The question of how to stop and EditText from taking focus on Activity Startup has been asked and answered here: [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

EditText has a method called `getSelectionStart()` which will return the position of the cursor if there is no text selected. `getSelectionEnd()` will return the position of the end of selection.

Another link: For the EditText curson question: [Get Cursor Position in Android in Edit Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900408/get-cursor-position-in-android-in-edit-text)
Hope that helps