# Get Cursor Position in Android in TransparentHintTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Want to replicate this Edit Text feature [Get Cursor Position in Android in Edit Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900408/4083142)
in Android Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 1):

To get text field selection in compose, you need to use `TextFieldValue`, like this:

```
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = "")) }

TextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = {
        textFieldValue = it
    },
)
```

Then you can get selection with `textFieldValue.selection`, for example on key event with `Modifier.onKeyEvent`, on button click, etc.